# How to classify quadratic forms using their signature

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

I just did a question asking to classify the kind of curve of a given quadratic polynomial: $$0=3x^2+8xy+6y^2+12x+20y+17$$

I completed the square a few times and eventually (correctly) observed that it is an ellipse.

However the solution I've been given simply uses a fact that we worked out in an earlier part of the question, specifically that the signature of the quadratic part of the polynomial is 2. According to the solution this directly implies that we have an ellipse.

This is something I haven't been taught and was wondering if we are always able to use the signature to classify a curve? Can we do something similar with surfaces?

If so, then what signatures determine what kind of curve/surface?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

First, you perhaps completed the square, but first should have gotten rid of that $\;xy\;$ term there by means of a transformation.

Second, in this precise case that *you say* is an ellipse, the signature doesn't help, but the *sign* of the determinants of the expanded and the reduced matrices, say $\;A\,,\,\,A_1\;$ resp., together with their range determine this:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}17&6&10\\6&3&4\\10&4&6\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\;A_1=\begin{pmatrix}3&4\\4&6\end{pmatrix}$$

so

$$\begin{cases}\det A<0\\{}\\\det A_1>0\\{}\\\text{rank}\,A=3\\{}\\\text{rank}\,A_1=2\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies\;\;\text{the quadratic is an ellipse.}$$

As you can see, the signature has no business in this case. It odes have though when we have two parallel lines or the empty set.

Comment: It can be done much easier than that. The [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant_classification), which in this case is $60-72 = -12$ is enough to tell what kind of conic it is (assuming it's not just two lines, a "double" line or the empty set).

Comment: Well, that's *a lot* of assuming if you know nothing to begin with, don't you think? Not to mention that matrices, determinants and etc. should be old and well-known stuff at the apparentl level of the OP.

Comment: Is there a general way of classifying curves or surfaces like this? Or do you know a website that explains it all?

Comment: @user229679 Using matrices and some of their characteristics, as in this case, we can classify *quadratics* . As for more general cases I doubt it, as otherwise algebraic geometry wouldn't be as interesting and rich a realm as it is.